# SwiftUI How to stop Button from triggering outside of its frame?

Tags: ios, function, button, swiftui, action

I'm trying to stop the following button from triggering when clicking outside of the border and only trigger the action when clicking inside the frame.

```
          Button(action: {
                                
                                model.addData(clubID: clubID, clubName: clubName, clubCreator: String(describing: uidx), membersLimit: membersLimit, streamingPlatforms: streamingPlatforms, streamingType: streamingType, teleClubGenres: teleClubGenres, date:  Date.getCurrentDate(), description: description, uid: String(describing: uidx) , currentMembers: [String(describing: uidx)], selectedDate: dateformatter(date: selectedDate), mediaChosen: mediaChosen, streamingPartyLink: streamingPartyLink)
                                isSuccess = true
                                message = "Club made successfully"
                                shown.toggle()

                                clubID = 0
                                clubName = ""
                                clubCreator = ""
                                membersLimit = 0
                                streamingPlatforms = 0
                                streamingType = 0
                                teleClubGenres = []
                                date = ""
                                description = ""
                                uid = ""
                                currentMembers = [String(describing: uidx)]
                                selectedDateTwo = ""
                                mediaChosen = ""
                                streamingPartyLink = "https://www.teleparty.com/"
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Save")
                                    .padding().foregroundColor(Color.black).background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(lineWidth: 2).background(Color.white.cornerRadius(10))).frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                                
                 
                            })
```

Comment: have you tried using `.clipped()`?

Comment: Please make your questions as minimal as possible! None of the code in the `action: {}` closure is needed for this example, and it makes the question hard to read. Feel free to edit the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you wanted this

```
Button(action: {
    // ... action here
}, label: {
    Text("Save").padding()
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .background(
           RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(lineWidth: 2)
              .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(10))
        )
})
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)    // << here !!
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and was able to fix it with `.clipped().buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())`

```
Button(action: {
    //action
}, label: {
    Text("Click").clipped().buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
}).clipped().buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

> and only trigger the action when clicking inside the frame

The last modifier on the text in your button is `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)`.

So, because you set `maxWidth` to `.infinity`, the button has an infinite frame. This means that the action **IS** only being triggered when clicking inside the frame, but you set the frame to be infinite, and so clicking *anywhere* will trigger the action.

Because you made the frame infinite, you're making the action area infinite, too, which is why clicking "anywhere" will trigger your button.